# QT Creator cannot create plain C++ Project or HTML5 project (QT Creator closed directly)

Tags: c++, html, qt4, qt-creator, ubuntu-12.04

I have problem with my QT Creator in my OS.
I'm using :

1. Ubuntu 12.04
2. QT Creator 2.4.1
3. QT 4.8.0

I try to create a new project and then choose "other project" and then try to choose "Plain C++ Projec".

But after I click "Plain C++ Project" or other kind project, the QT Creator is closed, except the first option or the default option that is "QT Console Application".

the error when i try to run with terminal in ubuntu is :
"QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "6"  obj:  QMenu(0x82ba3a8, name = "QtCreator.Menu.File") "QtCreator.Menu.File" 
QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "7"  obj:  QMenu(0x82ba3a8, name = "QtCreator.Menu.File") "QtCreator.Menu.File" 
FIXME: handle dialog start. 
QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "8008"  obj:  QObject(0x0)  " invalid interface!" 
QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "8008"  obj:  QObject(0x0)  " invalid interface!" 
Interface is not valid 
ASSERT failure in : "Got an update for an invalid inteface. Investigate this.", file atspiadaptor.cpp, line 899
Aborted (core dumped)
"

and not just for "Plain C++ Project" that cannot opened, but also for HTML 5 and all of optional project in "other project" menus.

i hope it can't be resolve.. 
please help...  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been resolved...
the problem is "atspiadaptor.cpp, line 899"
so to resolve it just remove the qt-at-spi package
couse the bug is in qt-at-spi package
(see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/959722 ).

sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi

:D